# I dont know whats wrong with this simple javascript code, I have checked this over and over again but does not work

Tags: javascript, function, events

Simple image expanding on mouseover and opposite on mouseout, I checked the code over and over, putting alert messages at each line to see if its working, alert message work all the way to the end but there is no effect on the image. I am so confused, I dunno whats wrong.

```js
var side = 200;
var a = 20;
var t = 0;


function expand() {
  console.log("expand is ok");
  clearInterval(t);
  t = setInterval(grow, 20);

}

function grow() {
   console.log("Entered grow");
  if (side < 300) {
    console.log("entered if loop");
    side = side + a;
    document.getElementById("new").style.width = side;
    console.log("After statement")
  } else
    clearInterval(t);
  console.log("clear")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Zoom in Zoom out</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="../images/women.jpg" id="new" alt="Women" onmouseover="expand()" width=2 00px>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try removing that (malformed) `width=2 00px` attribute...

Comment: Also: you don't really need JavaScript for this; a CSS `img {transition: width 1s; } img:hover { width: 300px; }` should be enough...

Comment: @AKX i dunno how 2 00px got separated in copy paste, in my code its normal. I am new at javascript just practicing events and functions. I am aware this can be done in css but not at 20 milli seconds per transition which in not important atm but I am practicing as I said earlier.

Comment: as you might have seen all alert boxes are activated till the end, I cant understand why the get element by id . style . width is not working, side is getting incremented as it is suppose to..

Comment: Try `.width = '' + side + 'px'` (or the equivalent template string) – CSS styles have units...

Comment: wow.. that fixed it... whats the reason for this(to remember for future).. thanks

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment:

The issue is you're trying to assign a raw number such as `200` to the width CSS property.

If you look at CSS, you'd spell "200 pixels" as

```
foo {
  width: 200px;
}
```

so similarly you'll need to endow the dynamic manipulation with an unit (pixels here):

```
foo.style.width = `${width}px`;
```